# Create all combinations of word with spaces

Tags: vb.net, console

Hello i'm trying to create a program in Visual Basic (console application) that checks for all combination of a word with spaces such as:

1. True
2. T r u e
3. T rue
4. T ru e
5. Tru e
6. Tr u e

Now the word cannot start or end with a space, and I was wondering how I should start off with this?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to generate those strings, you have to think about how you're going to do it. For a given word:

1. You take the first letter. After all, it cannot start with a space.
2. You have two options: insert a space, or continue to the next letter.
3. If you insert a space, continue to the next letter.
4. Repeat steps 2 and 3 for all letters until the last letter.
5. Add the last letter. After all, it cannot end with a space.

You can do this recursively.

---

If you just want to check for a word with spaces in it, then you can use a regular expression. Generate a pattern at run-time, something like this:

```
^T[ ]?r[ ]?u[ ]?e$
```

The `^` matches the start of the string, `$` the end. `[ ]?` matches a space *or not*. To match multiple spaces and/or tabs, use `\s*` instead.

Comment: Step 2: when to add space and when to continue?

Comment: @DanVerdolino Both: recurse as if you added a space, then when you've returned to the method, recurse as if you didn't add a space.